# Add A Custom Decoration To Container, Using Painter Class

Tags: flutter

I know I can give decoration to my container, and then provide a border to it.
But I am trying to Wrap my `Container` with some Custom border using Custom Paint `class`, The Custom Paint Class should surround or provide a `border` to `container` like a `dashed` `border` or any custom shape border,

**Note:- Please Don't suggest me to use any custom package like dashed Border, I want the answer in the form of Custom Painter like BoxPainter class etc.**

*So, Far I have wrote this `code`*

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustPaint extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        decoration: CustomDecoration(),
        child: new Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDecoration extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([void Function() onChanged]) {
    return BoxDecorationPainter();
  }
}

class BoxDecorationPainter extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final Rect bounds = offset & configuration.size;
    _drawDecoration(canvas, bounds);
  }
}

void _drawDecoration(Canvas canvas, Rect size) {
  var radius = min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
  var circleRaidus = radius * .012;
  var paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.teal
    ..strokeWidth = circleRaidus * .5
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

  for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    Offset topRight = Offset(size.left + i * 4, size.top);
    Offset downLeft = Offset(size.left, size.top + i * 4);
    Offset bottomRight = Offset(size.left + i * 4, size.bottom);
    Offset downRight = Offset(size.right, size.top + i * 4);

    canvas.drawCircle(topRight, circleRaidus * 2, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bottomRight, circleRaidus * 2, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(downRight, circleRaidus * 2, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(downLeft, circleRaidus * 2, paint);
  }
}
```

**And What I have Achieved is**

[image]

But The **OUTPUT**

1. I want is that all the `lines` (with tiny circles) should join and there should be no `gap` in between them while meeting `corner` to `corner`. (means they should join to cover the container like a square or rectangle)
2. Also I want to give some `space` between those tiny `circles` like
   some `padding`.
3. It would be a plus if those `circles` can be
   replaced by any `image`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you cannot use both fixed `60` and `i * 4` - you want always `60` circles on every side or circles have to be placed every `4` logical pixels?

Comment: say I want n Circles on the sides, then how will I implement it in the code, that they will make a square or rectangle by joining their sides, with some padding between those tiny circles.

Comment: @pskink Actually I tried your solution, but I think i implemented it wrong way, Coz those line does not meet either to form a square or rectangle and also there was no padding seen between those tiny circles, May be you can write a answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @pskink Your Code works perfectly Thanks, But can you Explain the code, Coz there is so much math in that, and I suck at maths.

Comment: what i meant was about computeMetrics and getTangentForOffset and rect.deflate

Comment: okay, but can't it more easy and simple, like Thierry answer but with some n defined and padding variable between those circles.

Answer (score 3):

The number of circles has to be adapted to the size of the box:

```
final nbShapes = [
  ((bounds.width + gap) / (shapeSize + gap)).floor(),
  ((bounds.height + gap) / (shapeSize + gap)).floor(),
];
```

[image]

In my Solution, the CustomDecorationBox can be configured with:

- `double shapeSize`, the size of the shapes,
- `double shapeGap`, the gap between two shapes,
- `Paint shapePaint`, the paint used to draw the shapes (support for both strokes and fill paints)
- `ShapePainter paintShape`, a function painting the shapes

I provided 3 ShapePainter samples:

- `paintCircle()`
- `paintRectangle()`
- `ShapePainter createNGonPainter(int n)`, a factory for n-gon painters

---

Full source code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef ShapePainter = void Function(Canvas, Rect, Paint);

Random random = Random();

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CustomDecoration Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          final size = Size(1, .6) * constraints.biggest.width;
          print(size);
          return GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: List.generate(
              120,
              (index) => Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(size.width * .01),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: CustomDecoration(
                    shapeSize: 5.0 + random.nextInt(10),
                    shapeGap: 2.0 + random.nextInt(3),
                    shapePaint: Paint()
                      ..color = Color(0x99000000 + random.nextInt(0xffffff))
                      ..strokeWidth = random.nextInt(3).toDouble()
                      ..style = random.nextInt(3) == 2
                          ? PaintingStyle.fill
                          : PaintingStyle.stroke,
                    paintShape: random.nextInt(4) == 0
                        ? paintCircle
                        : createNGonPainter(3 + random.nextInt(5)),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      index.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDecoration extends Decoration {
  final double shapeSize;
  final double shapeGap;
  final Paint shapePaint;
  final ShapePainter paintShape;

  CustomDecoration({
    this.shapeSize,
    this.shapeGap,
    this.shapePaint,
    this.paintShape,
  }) : super();

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([void Function() onChanged]) {
    return BoxDecorationPainter(
        shapeSize: shapeSize ?? 10,
        shapeGap: shapeGap ?? 4,
        shapePaint: shapePaint ?? Paint(),
        paintShape: paintShape ?? paintCircle);
  }
}

class BoxDecorationPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final double shapeSize;
  final double shapeGap;
  final Paint shapePaint;
  final ShapePainter paintShape;

  BoxDecorationPainter({
    this.shapeSize,
    this.shapeGap,
    this.shapePaint,
    this.paintShape,
  }) : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final Rect bounds = offset & configuration.size;
    _drawDecoration(canvas, bounds, shapeSize, shapeGap);
  }

  void _drawDecoration(
      Canvas canvas, Rect bounds, double shapeSize, double gap) {
    final nbShapes = [
      ((bounds.width + gap) / (shapeSize + gap)).floor(),
      ((bounds.height + gap) / (shapeSize + gap)).floor(),
    ];
    final correctedGaps = [
      (bounds.width - nbShapes[0] * shapeSize) / (nbShapes[0] - 1),
      (bounds.height - nbShapes[1] * shapeSize) / (nbShapes[1] - 1),
    ];
    final steps = [
      correctedGaps[0] + shapeSize,
      correctedGaps[1] + shapeSize,
    ];

    for (int i = 0; i < nbShapes[0]; i++) {
      paintShape(
        canvas,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          bounds.left + steps[0] * i,
          bounds.top,
          shapeSize,
          shapeSize,
        ),
        shapePaint,
      );
      paintShape(
        canvas,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          bounds.left + steps[0] * i,
          bounds.bottom - shapeSize,
          shapeSize,
          shapeSize,
        ),
        shapePaint,
      );
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < nbShapes[1] - 1; i++) {
      paintShape(
        canvas,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          bounds.left,
          bounds.top + steps[1] * i,
          shapeSize,
          shapeSize,
        ),
        shapePaint,
      );
      paintShape(
        canvas,
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          bounds.right - shapeSize,
          bounds.top + steps[1] * i,
          shapeSize,
          shapeSize,
        ),
        shapePaint,
      );
    }
  }
}

void paintCircle(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds, Paint paint) {
  canvas.drawCircle(
    Offset(
      bounds.left + bounds.width / 2,
      bounds.top + bounds.height / 2,
    ),
    bounds.shortestSide / 2,
    paint,
  );
}

void paintRectangle(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds, Paint paint) {
  canvas.drawRect(bounds, paint);
}

ShapePainter createNGonPainter(int n) => (canvas, bounds, paint) {
      Path path = Path();
      path.moveTo(
        bounds.left + (bounds.width + cos(2 * pi / n) * bounds.width) / 2,
        bounds.top + (bounds.height + sin(2 * pi / n) * bounds.height) / 2,
      );
      for (var k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
        path.lineTo(
          bounds.left + (bounds.width + cos(2 * k * pi / n) * bounds.width) / 2,
          bounds.top +
              (bounds.height + sin(2 * k * pi / n) * bounds.height) / 2,
        );
      }
      path.close();
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    };
```

Comment: Your Code works as perfectly as I want, but you forgot to add padding between those circles, Can you please add those.

Comment: Sky is the limit! I'll update my answer with more math, especially for you. 